# AWS Route 53 Subdomain Not Propagating

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain (e.g. `mydomain.com`) and two subdomains (e.g. `aarc.mydomain.com`, and `api.mydomain.com`) in Route 53.

The domain is owned by GoDaddy.

I can successfully ping the domain (`mydomain.com`) and one of the subdomains (`aarc.mydomain.com`) successfully.

However, I recently added `api.mydomain.com` as an A Record to point to the alias of an Elastic Load Balancer, and have not been able to get a ping response.

The TTL for the Name Servers was set to 48 hours, so I changed the TTL to 3600 and have waited 2 days.

I am still getting the following error on a ping: `Ping request could not find host api.###########.com. Please check the name and try again.`

Any Thoughts?

---

**Update:**

Including a screenshot of the ping efforts:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't ping an ELB.  However, you *should* get back an IP address, followed by `Request timed out`.  That is the normal behavior.  For any further troubleshooting, you're going to need to mention your domain name.  We can't really inspect for common misconfigurations, otherwise.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks Michael. The subdomain that is not returning an IP address is `api.sadvhub.com`. The subdomain that is, is `aarc.sadvhub.com`. I've also added a screenshot of my ping attempts.

Comment: If the question gets downvoted, please provide feedback so I can provide a higher quality question.

Answer (score 0):

Your domain is not configured with AWS nameservers as authoritative, so anything you enter in Route53 is simply not used.

You have to go to Registrar where you registered you domain and add the 4 AWS name servers (from the above Route53 screenshot). Since it seems that GoDaddy is your registrar, probably this can help: [Set custom nameservers for domains registered with GoDaddy](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-godaddy-12317)

Keep in mind that all records that you have previously created at Godaddy DNS console, you will have to enter them again to Route53 (and do that before you change authoritative name servers).

If you don't own the domain and changing authoritative name servers is not an option, you can either:

1. Just ask the client to add the desired record `api.sadvhub.com` in Goddady DNS console (you can't use AWS `ALIAS` there of course so you will go with `CNAME`)

or

2. If you want to have the ability to add new records by your self in the future (and have the client keep his current Goddady DNS setup and records), create the new subdomain zone in Route53, for example `aero.advhub.com`, then note the NS records for the new zone (they will be different from the above ones) and ask client to add those NS records for the subdomain to Godaddy sadvhub.com, zone, something like this:

.

```
aero.sadvhub.com    NS    ns-xxx.awsdns-yy.com
aero.sadvhub.com    NS    ns-aaa.awsdns-zz.org
aero.sadvhub.com    NS    ns-bbb.awsdns-qq.net
aero.sadvhub.com    NS    ns-ccc.awsdns-pp.co.uk
```

After that you can (in Route53) create and use records like `api.aero.sadvhub.com` or  `anything.aero.sadvhub.com`.

Comment: @DusanBajaic Thanks for your answer Dusan. I don't own the domain, so i'll have to work with the owner next week to test what you suggest.

Comment: Really appreciate your input, Dusan, thank you. I'll work with the client after the new year holiday and upvote/accept your answer as correct when I can confirm it worked.

Comment: @Dusan I tried this solution (2nd listed item). Still new subdomain results in no host found on http or ping. Is there a change in the process now?

Comment: @sumanj Please post new question (preferably with your real domain name, that will make troubleshooting much easier)